Custom CSS is not being applied to custom jstree icons
I am trying to show custom images in Jstree but the custom Jstree images/icons are not populating in UI. though, if I add background-size=80%; manually in the browser then the images will show but when I try with JS function it's not working. this happened after I updated struts2-jquery-tree-plugin to 4.0.3
Here is what I am doing.
<sjt:tree name="searchtree"
id="jsonTree"
href="%{treeDataUrl}"
formIds="formsearch"
jstreetheme="default"
onCompleteTopics="setImagesSize,showDivPagination,selectItemOnLoadTreeComplete"
onClickTopics="selectTreeItem"
showThemeDots="true"
showThemeIcons="true"
/>

JS function
$.subscribe('setImagesSize', function(event, data) {    
        var ins = document.getElementById('jsonTree').getElementsByTagName('i');
        for(var i = 0; i < ins.length; i++) {
            if(ins[i].style.backgroundImage!=null && ins[i].style.backgroundImage!=''){
               ins[i].style.backgroundSize = "100%";
               if(ins[i].style.backgroundImage.indexOf("license")!=-1){
                  ins[i].style.backgroundSize = "85%"; 
               }
            }
        }
    });

I am assigning an image path in my action class.
also if I give some sleep time then only the root node images/icons are shown.
please guide me to this.

You should clarify your problem and add details to be able to diagnose your problem. As far as it's written is impossible to suggest you anything.
